# Unable to withdraw liquidity on pancakewsap v1

Tags: solidity, pancakeswap, liquidity-provider

Please I really need help here.

My smart contract was deployed on pancakeswap V2 using RouterV1.

I already added liquidity but then discovered I couldn't swap. I have created a new smart contract on with RouterV2 but the problem is I am unable to withdraw the liquidity on the former one.

I have done the following:

1. Set liquidityfee to 0
2. Set tax to 0
3. Set MaxTxPercent to 100

Each time i try to withdraw liquidity on pancakeswap, I get the following error

```
{code: -32603, message: "Internal JSON-RPC error.", data: {…}}
code: -32603
data: {code: 3, message: "execution reverted: PancakeRouter: INSUFFICIENT_A_AMOUNT", data: "0x08000000…0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}
message: "Internal JSON-RPC error."
```

```
estimateGas failed 0 removeLiquidityETHWithPermit (10) ["0x1B5d0E2473xxx", "31819805153394637698", "44448462829941701997", "22416422399999999365", "0x349ad59xxx", 1621684887, false, 28, "0xb335b5468887xxx", "0x7323f344xxx"]
```

```
estimateGas failed 1 removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens 
(10) ["0x1B5d0E2473aFC5A70CC026dDD45547Fe7830ba9b", "31819805153394637698", "44448462829941701997", "22416422399999999365", "0x349ad597cA4033f766F3ae2C870187a0454fD7F3", 1621684887, false, 28, "0xb335b5468887ef414cec86d5fff3f432a5cf01e5313ea7f16ec9f8b0add8bd56", "0x7323f344e59f0553xxx"]
0: "0x1B5dxxx"
1: "31819805153394637698"
2: "44448462829941701997"
3: "22416422399999999365"
4: "0x349ad5xxx"
5: 1621684887
6: false
7: 28
8: "0xb335b5468xxx"
9: "0x7323f344xxx"
length: 10
 
{code: -32603, message: "Internal JSON-RPC error.", data: {…}}
code: -32603
data:
code: 3
data: "0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000"
message: "execution reverted: PancakeRouter: INSUFFICIENT_A_AMOUNT"
```

Comment: did you find the fix? I cannot withdraw either

Comment: Do you have a link to the contracts? and the contract's source code.